# VC++ fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.exe for writing

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++

Suddenly, my Visual Studio Express 2010 C++ stopped rebuilding my project.
When I first hit <kbd>F7</kbd> the project builds and runs fine (heck, it's a hello world example).

Then I make some changes and hit <kbd>F7</kbd> again, then I get:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\console\Debug\console.exe for writing**<br><br>
```

Now the funny thing comes:

1. The app is not running and it's not shown in the Task Manager.
2. Going into the project directory and trying to remove it with hands comes with success  but the file APPEARS AGAIN FROM NOWHERE.
3. The system restore is disabled.
4. I also tried to take the ownership of the whole damn drive.
5. Every time I delete the file it recreates itself again but sometimes it stops doing that.
6. If I delete the file (and it recreates after that), and then I start sysinternals procmon then the file disappears.
7. If I start procmon before - then the file keeps appearing after delete like always.

OS: W7 SP1 64-bit, with latest updates

Any ideas, please?

Comment: For me a simple reboot fixed this error (similar to CodeMed's answer below).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Enable “Application Experience” service.  Launch a console window and type `net start AeLookupSvc`

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902196

Comment: Windows 10 gives me the error : "The service name is invalid"

Comment: How do I enable application experience?

Comment: It worked for me. Another ridiculous Windows hack. Microsoft should pay Google a hefty sum for supporting its OS, otherwise no one would be able to use the thing.

Comment: Worked for me on windows 7 Visual Studio 2013 C++

Comment: @AhmetTavli I have the same problem. The service seems to not be available in Win10. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Astinog I have been using Mac for more than 2 years, therefore I forgot the solution. I'm sorry

Answer (score 105):

The problem is probably that you forgot to close the program and that you instead have the program running in the background.

Find the console window where the exe file program is running, and close it by clicking the X in the upper right corner.  Then try to recompile the program.  In my case this solved the problem.

I know this posting is old, but I am answering for the other people like me who find this through the search engines.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I will say though, I had to look under processes in windows task manager, because the console window disappeared.

Comment: I am not able to close by X button is there any other way...? One way i found is lose your IDE and then it will automatically close prompt window.

Comment: Win10 VS 2017. Quitting everything until there was nothing of relevance in the task manager doesn't help, instead I have to reboot the machine. When shutting down an error dialog suddenly appears and is immediately closed out of, presumably this dialog needed to be closed before the debugger could access the app again but the dialog does not appear (until shutting down). Perhaps this process existed in the task manager but with a generic/unhelpful name.

Comment: Adding to my above comment, **Task Manager does not display the filename.exe process but Resource Monitor does**, so I'm able to kill it from there which solves the issue without having to reboot.

Comment: @CodeMed oopsie..this is why I love StackOverflow

Comment: Hey A__, you have saved my time a lot. I used to reboot my computer and it was so annoying and time-consuming. none of those above worked. but your solution was the only one works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow, I am a Kufing idiot. You know, you might think that MS would suggest that you check to make sure your command-line application is closed... FML...

Answer (score 21):

I've encountered this problem when the build is abruptly closed before it is loaded. No process would show up in the Task Manager, but if you navigate to the executable generated in the project folder and try to delete it, Windows claims that the application is in use. (If not, just delete the file and rebuild, which generates a new executable)
In Windows(Visual Studio 2019), the file is located in this directory by default:

```
%USERPROFILE%\source\repos\ProjectFolderName\Debug
```

To end the allegedly running process, open the command prompt and type in the following command:

```
taskkill /F /IM ApplicationName.exe
```

This forces any running instance to be terminated.
Rebuild and execute!

Answer (score 13):

Restarting Visual Studio solved the problem for me.

Comment: I actually had to restart the whole computer.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, cleaning and rebuilding the project resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If the above solutions didn't work, you can try this which worked for me.

Open an elevated command prompt (`cmd -> Run as administrator`), then write following command and hit enter:

```
wmic process where name='YOUR_PROCESS_NAME.exe' delete
```

If you see a message: `Instance deletion successful.`, then you will be again able to build and run project from VS.

e.g. in OP's case, the command will be:

```
wmic process where name='console.exe' delete
```

Answer (score 1):

well, I actually just saved and closed the project and restarted VS Express 2013 in windows 8 and that sorted my problem.

Comment: Hi Sparsh Jain, the question mentioned that "*visual studio express 2010*" on "*W7 SP1*" was being used. Moreover I don't think that your answer doesn't add anything that existing answers haven't covered.

Comment: Thanks! I did that with VS 2015 on windows 10 and it helped me :) I think that's the easiest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Reason is that your previous build is still running in the background.
I solve this problem by following these steps:

- Open Task Manager
- Goto Details Tab
- Find Your Application
- End Task it by right clicking on it
- Done!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I was stumbling in the same problem also. Finding it in task manager is tricky, and I started to grow tired of having to restart my PC every time this happened.

A solution would be to download [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and there you can search for running tasks. In my case I was having the following error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:Out\Build\VS12_app\Debug\platform_test.exe for writing [C:Build\VS12_app\platform_test.vcxproj]

I searched for `C:Out\Build\VS12_app\Debug\platform_test.exe` in Process Explorer, killed it and I was able to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers to this question provide one-off, manual solutions to the problem.  However, the root cause of the problem in many cases is that Visual Studio is leaving your previous debug session's process running, or at least extant in a way that maintains a lock on the executable file.  You can set Visual Studio to automatically kill such a process when you stop debugging.  This would then typically prevent you from getting this error, as well as needing to take manual steps to rectify it.

To instruct Visual Studio to automatically kill the process when debugging stops, set the following option:

Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General-->Automatically close the console when debugging stops

On Visual Studio 2022 this is very near the bottom of this list.

Personally, I will run a process under Visual Studio with F5 (Debug) which compiles and links the binary first if necessary.

Then the binary crashes, or hits a breakpoint, or I'm tired of waiting, so I will change the source then hit SHIFT-F5 F5.  This is "Debug Stop" followed by "Debug" again.  I just do that by reflex.

I'm not sure if this flag's default value changes periodically between releases of Visual Studio, but I don't recall ever having to set this option before.  I generally create very few projects but work on them many years, so maybe I set this option manually every time then forget about it.  But on 2022, it does need to be set.  I've set it and now can work as I recall working in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this same issue. My console window was no longer open, but I was able to see my application running by going to processes within task manager. The process name was the name of my application. Once I ended the process I was able to build and compile my code with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be a problem from the improper use of functions like FindNextFile when a FindClose is never executed. The process of the built file is terminated, and the build itself can be deleted, but LNK1168 will prevent a rebuild because of the open handle. This can create a handle leak in Explorer which can be addressed by terminating and restarting Explorer, but in many cases an immediate reboot is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but thought I'd share how I resolved the issue.

If you're using Visual Studio and this error occurs, you can try to attach to process (CTRL+ALT+P) and find the "(program).exe" process. When you try to attach to it, an error will display stating that it failed to attach which removes the process from "running" (even though it's not...) You'll also be able to delete the (program).exe from your Debug folder.

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

**FINALLY THE BEST WAY WORKED PERFECTLY FOR ME**

None of the solutions in this page worked for me ***EXCEPT THE FOLLOWING***

Below the comment sections of the second answer, try the following :

> Adding to my above comment, *Task Manager* does not display the
> filename.exe process but ***Resource Monitor does***, so I'm able to
> kill it from there which solves the issue ***without having to reboot.*** –
> A__ Jun 19 '19 at 21:23

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above suggested work for you, which was the case for me, just change the project name. It creates a new exe in the new project name.  Later when you restart, you can change it back to your original project name.

Answer (score -4):

Start your program as an administrator. The program can't rewrite your files cause your files are in a protected location on your hard drive.