# Visual Studio C Programing 'Fatal Error LNK1168'?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 C programming but I get an error like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xztjf.png

I try it but does not work : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17500526/2184315

Comment: If the program is not running in the background (check using task manager) you can switch between debug and release modes and try building in each of those configurations.

Comment: If at all possible, please copy-and-paste the error message *as text* into your question rather than linking to an image. Also, please indicate what you were doing when you got the error message.