# LNK1168: cannot open debug\file.exe for writing

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator, qt5

I have qt project but if I edit my code, Qt creator throws out this error

`:-1: error: LNK1168: cannot open debug\GettingStarted.exe for writing`

I'm not able even to delete the debug folder (i.e. as an administrator). I have to log off and then come back. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is the program still running? Is it open in a debugger?

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes indeed but I don't know why this occurs? I'm trying to open cam with OpenCV. Once I quit the app, it seems something is running in the background.

Comment: Maybe you can use Task Manager to see what extra stuff is running (compared to what is running before you build and debug).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VC++ fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.exe for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124146/vc-fatal-error-lnk1168-cannot-open-filename-exe-for-writing)

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to the task manager <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.
2. look for the name of your running application in your case `GettingStarted.exe`.
3. `right click --> end process` or just press `Suppr` . This will kill the running process.
4. Go back to your code and run the application again

Comment: If you can't find your `*.exe` in the `Processes` tab of the `Task Manager`, then search in the `Details` tab

Answer (score 3):

In my simple case (Qt only, no external libs, same error LNK1168)  the Task manager showed nothing useful to kill. 
Only total reboot has helped and error is gone.

Comment: yeah what a mess.... any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

All the methods mentioned here has not helped except reboot. There is no any ProjectName.exe in Task Manager.
You can go to `C:\Users\user-name\source\repos\ProjectName\Debug\` folder and rename `ProjectName.exe`. You can't delete this file at that time, but It can be renamed. It can only be deleted after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I was stumbling in the same problem also. Finding it in task manager is tricky, and I started to grow tired of having to restart my PC every time this happened.

A solution would be to download Process Explorer and there you can search for running tasks. In my case I was having the following error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open C:Out\Build\VS12_app\Debug\platform_test.exe for writing [C:Build\VS12_app\platform_test.vcxproj]
```

I searched for C:Out\Build\VS12_app\Debug\platform_test.exe in Process Explorer, killed it and I was able to compile.

Comment: it's same procedure by using task manager.

Answer (score 0):

When a program fails with a runtime error, the exe may still be running in the background. So it must be stopped in task manager by ending the process so that the compiler (vscode) can replace the exe. Also a good idea to stop and start vscode.