# Something wrong with this Loop?

Tags: c, list, api, directory

The code that embeds the loop builds and runs fine. Attempting to build it (VS10 in MBCS) with it in fails at the LinkEmbedManifest step with the [link 1168](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124146/vc-fatal-error-lnk1168-cannot-open-filename-exe-for-writing) error.

```
    WIN32_FIND_DATA da;   // directory data
    TCHAR *Path;    // directory Pointer
    HANDLE ds;     // directory handle  
    int Listindex=0;
    Path = "C:\\";
    SetCurrentDirectory(Path);     
    Listindex=0
    ds = FindFirstFile(TEXT("*"),&da);
        do       {
            int index = SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_LIST, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)Listindex, (LPARAM)&da);

            SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_LIST, LB_SETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)index, (LPARAM)Listindex);
            Listindex+=1;
            } 
            while( FindNextFile(ds,&da) != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS);


    FindClose(ds);
```

The aim is to list the directories in the root of C. There is implicit casting from  LONG_PTR LRESULT to int with index, and further casting with LPARAM and WPARAM. Would it make any difference if these were replaced with module-wide decs?
Or would changing the type of loop altogether be any better?

Comment: `da` is a [`WIN32_FIND_DATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure (I assume), why do you try to add a pointer to it as a string to the libsbox? Wouldn't it make more sense in passing `da.cFileName`? Also, you're are passing the same pointer each time you try to add the structure so all the entries would be the same anyway.

Comment: Oops, thanks- [face-palm] put those in. I guess with something like a Listindex would be more apropos. A FOR loop perhaps?

Comment: @Joachim-Pileborg, Windows copies the string from SendMessage to an internal string so the entries in the listbox will not be the same.

Comment: It builds fine now, but the pacman exe is an avid memory cruncher. The listbox never shows. Something will have to change here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW the question had so many errors, no wonder it was marked down. The biggest problem was testing for ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS on the entire da record and not da.cFileName, thus the infinite loop:.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winnt.h>
#include "resource.h" //Listbox data

WIN32_FIND_DATA da;   // directory data this will use stack memory as opposed to LPWIN32_FIND_DATA
TCHAR *driveIDptr;  
char driveID;
HANDLE ds;     // directory handle

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(Msg)
{
        case WM_INITDIALOG:

{       
    int listindex = 0;

    //Populate List
    driveIDptr = "C:\\*";
    memset(&da, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    ds = FindFirstFile(driveIDptr, &da);
    driveIDptr = "C:\\"; //Shocking, but costs less than a strcat in above find function

    if (ds == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
     StringCchPrintf (pszDest, cbDest, TEXT("No directories found."));
    return FALSE;
    }

    while (ds != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE && ds)
    {

        if (FindNextFile(ds, &da) == FALSE) break;

    if((da.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) && !(da.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM
|| da.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT || da.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_ARCHIVE || da.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN )) {

    strcpy (&driveID, (char *) driveIDptr);
    strcat (&driveID,  da.cFileName);
    SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_LIST, LB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)listindex, (LPARAM)&driveID);

        SendDlgItemMessage(hwnd, IDC_LIST, LB_SETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)listindex, (LPARAM)listindex);
        listindex+=1;
    }

    } 
        FindClose(ds);

        //other Msg cases...
```