# visual studio 2015 hangs on default console application file during debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

The default file when I select console application is

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

When I click "local windows debugger", the program freezes and nothing happens. Is it possible my debug compiler is not linked to the correct executables?

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? If so, try disabling it and then test your program. There have been several similar questions on SO recently and Avast was the problem.

Comment: @Blastfurnace How do I disable Avast?

Comment: I don't use Avast so I can't answer that. There should also be a way to add an exclusion for your project folder somewhere in the Avast settings. That would be preferable to completely disabling your antivirus.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I discovered that Avast was the problem. Simply disabling Avast fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The way it's currently written this will result in a syntax error compilation fault because you forgot a `;` after `return 0`. It's most likely just instantly closing the program though, try to run this code and check if it prints out :

> Hello, World!

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

If this still "freezes" your debugger then I suggest reinstalling your Visual Studio.

Comment: I apolgies. I typed the program by hand and I forgot the semi-colon. The program in visual studio does have a semi-colon. How do I reinstall visual studio? I cannot find an option to perform a complete uninstall.

Comment: @linuxfreebird Does this mean that even after running my example code you're still getting a freeze?

Comment: I get the same error. Output says fatal error cannot open .exe for writing.

Comment: Pop up says : project out of date

Comment: @linuxfreebird that means that the compiler can't write the final .exe file to disk(or the linker rather). Have you checked if it has the permission to do so?

Comment: No. How do I check permissions?

Comment: Running Visual Studio in administrative mode did not fix the problem.

Comment: @linuxfreebird check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/12124146/1870760

Comment: The problem was Avast. Simply disabling it fixed it for me.