# lnk1168 error Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I know there is a lot written on the topic, but nothing seems to help in my case. I keep getting lnk1168 error whenever I try to run a solution. exe appears in Task Manager and can not be closed with TM or Process Explorer. Applicaton Experience configuration has no effect either as well as reinstalling VS (I've already tried 2015 and 2012 versions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VC++ fatal error LNK1168: cannot open filename.exe for writing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124146/vc-fatal-error-lnk1168-cannot-open-filename-exe-for-writing)

Comment: it is, but neither of solutions from that topic helps